# how to trim trailing spaces after all delimiter in a text file

Tags: regex, perl, unix, awk, sed

Need help to remove trailing spaces after all delimiter in a text file
I have Text file with below data.
eg.

```
            ADDRESS_ID|         COUNTRY_TP_CD|       RESIDENCE_TP_CD|      PROV_STATE_TP_CD|ADDR_LINE_ONE|P_ADDR_LINE_ONE
  885637959852960985.0|                  76.0|||169 Park lane||Scottish||lane||KU|||||||2013-09-19 14:48:49.609000|
```

I want to remove spaces after the delimiter and the first letter of the word.
Any regex or unix script that can do the same. Looking for output as below:

```
ADDRESS_ID|COUNTRY_TP_CD|RESIDENCE_TP_CD|PROV_STATE_TP_CD|ADDR_LINE_ONE|P_ADDR_LINE_ONE
885637959852960985.0|76.0|||169 Park lane||Scottish||lane||KU||||||2013-09-19 14:48:49.609000|
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below perl code would remove the spaces which are present at the start of a line or the spaces after to the delimiter `|` ,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\|) +|^ +//g' file
ADDRESS_ID|COUNTRY_TP_CD|RESIDENCE_TP_CD|PROV_STATE_TP_CD|ADDR_LINE_ONE|P_ADDR_LINE_ONE
885637959852960985.0|76.0|||169 Park lane||Scottish||lane||KU|||||||2013-09-19 14:48:49.609000|
```

To save the changes made to that file,

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=\|) +|^ +//g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$i)} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner to remove the spacing around every field.   Assumes no embedded delimiters:

```
perl -i -lpe 's/\s*([^|]*?)\s*/$1/g' file.txt
```

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\ //g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: That will replace all blank chars, not just those at the start/end of fields, and won't replace tabs, and needlessly escapes the blank.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -r -e 's/(^|\|)\s+/\1/g' -e 's/\s+$//' filename
```

In the first expression:

- `(^|\|)` matches the beginning of the line or a `|` character, and saves this in capture group 1.
- `\s+` matches a sequence of whitespace characters after that.
- The replacement `\1` substitutes capture group 1, so this deletes the whitespace at the beginning of the line and after the delimiter.
- The `g` modifier makes it operate on all the matches in the line.

In the second expression:

- `\s+` again matches a sequence of whitespace
- `$` matches the end of the line
- The replacement replaces the whole thing with an empty string, this removing trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

for posix sed (for GNU sed add `--posix`)
    sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/|[[:space:]]*/|/g' YourFile

use 2 substitution (there are no OR (`|`) in sed regex posix version)

1. Remove starting space by replacing space at start( `^[[:space:]]*`) by nothing
2. Replace any sequence pipe than any space (`|[[:space:]]*`) by pipe

`[[:space:]]` could be replace by a single space char if text only have space (ASCII 32) char